# Microsoft Face Api key limit

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using Microsoft Face Api to verify two images.
I have created the api key as the picture given below.

[image]

There are two api keys generated.
I am confused about these two keys , whether the quota limit of 30k per month is applicable for both the keys or individually for one key is 30k per month.
And one more is there any validity period of the key.

Comment: related?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/identity-quotas-limits

Answer (score 3):

Both keys use the same back-end account, so the 30k quota is the combined usage of both keys.  There are two keys as this helps with secret renewal scenarios.

I am not sure what you mean by the validity period of the key, but you can see the expiration date of those keys is 3/17, after which time you will need to purchase API keys on Azure.